# Convert third party hosted http image url to a https url dynamically

Tags: java, http

I hava a java web app where I process millions of records and along with that tens of millions of images. These images generally get downloaded from a partner image server daily and then rehosted on my image server. I'm exploring the idea of not hosting the images on my image server and just calling them directly from the partner server. The problem I face is my site is a secure https site and the images are coming from a non secure http site. This causing a flag with my ssl certificate saying there is insecure content on the page.

My question is how can I convert that image to an https image? My initial thought was to somehow stream the image from my partner site through my backend to my frontend creating my own url to it, but I'm thinking that it would double the load time for the end user as it'd have to first download to my server process and then download to the client.

These images change daily, so I'm really trying to cut down on image processing time / I/O, image hosting, and data transfer. Any ideas would be helpful.

Comment: the only solution - ask another site to provide https, or you have to proxy them via your server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

proxy in your webserver (appache???) you could proxy/rewrite the https links to images to your partner server.

Comment: Yes, I use apache. I never gave that a thought, excellent idea. Thank you